# $(document).on(..) event works but not $("body").on(..) for dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically created element

```
<a class="update-link">
```

with `path: body > div#MySection > table> tbody > tr > td > div > a.update-link`.

When I bind event using

```
$(document).on("click", ".update-link", fn)
```

The event is triggered.

When I use `$("body")` or `$("#MySection")`, the event is not triggered. `$(document)` works but is inefficient due to the large scope. Why don't the more specific selectors work?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Direct vs. Delegated - jQuery .on()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: It work http://jsfiddle.net/yexogdtp/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a context through with your event delegation:

```js
$(() => {
  $(document, ".sec", "button").on("click", () => {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  
  $(".sec").append("<button>Test</button>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="sec"></section>
```

So in your case, `.sec` would be `body` or `#MySection`.